# Set selection font size in RichTextBox for multiple fonts in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I want to change to font size in `RichTextBox` using a combo box. It's easy to change the font size if we have one font in our selection text using this code.

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(SelectionFont.FontFamily, CInt(ToolStripComboBox3.Text), RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style)
```

But if we have multiple fonts in our selection it does not work.

I have another selection of code to solve this problem. But the only problem with this code is that it is good for less then 2000 characters - but when the selection text is large it is worthless. Please see code below:

```
 Public rtbTemp As New RichTextBox()
    Public Sub ChangeFontSize(ByVal rtb As RichTextBox, ByVal fontSize As Single)
        'This method should handle cases that occur when multiple fonts/styles are selected
        ' Parameters:-
        ' fontSize - the fontsize to be applied, eg 33.5
        If fontSize <= 0.0 Then
            Throw New System.InvalidProgramException("Invalid font size parameter to ChangeFontSize")
        End If
        Dim rtb1start As Integer = rtb.SelectionStart
        Dim len As Integer = rtb.SelectionLength
        Dim rtbTempStart As Integer = 0
        ' If len <= 1 and there is a selection font, amend and return
        If len <= 1 AndAlso rtb.SelectionFont IsNot Nothing Then
            rtb.SelectionFont = New Font(rtb.SelectionFont.FontFamily, fontSize, rtb.SelectionFont.Style)
            Return
        End If
        ' Step through the selected text one char at a time
        rtbTemp.Rtf = rtb.SelectedRtf
        For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1
            rtbTemp.[Select](rtbTempStart + i, 1)
            rtbTemp.SelectionFont = New Font(rtbTemp.SelectionFont.FontFamily, fontSize, rtbTemp.SelectionFont.Style)
        Next

        ' Replace & reselect
        rtbTemp.[Select](rtbTempStart, len)
        rtb.SelectedRtf = rtbTemp.SelectedRtf
        rtb.[Select](rtb1start, len)
        Return
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:
Xaml for Font Size Combo Box:

```
            <ComboBox Width="50" Name="FontsSizeCombo" FontSize="12" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="9" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="10" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="11" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="12" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="14" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="16" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="18" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="22" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="24" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="26" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="36" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="48" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="72" />
            </ComboBox>
```

Working Vb.Net Code:

```
Private Sub FontsSizeCombo_DropDownClosed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FontsSizeCombo.DropDownClosed
    mainRTB.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontSizeProperty, FontsSizeCombo.Text)
End Sub
```

mainRtb is my rich text box. Please check this as answer if it is correct.  Thank you.

Comment: Error: Selection is not member of  System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
iam using VB2008 EXpress

Comment: Then it require framework 3.5, iam working in framework 2.0, hoping for any other solution

Comment: Moving to higher .net is a good option at this point of time, it is only my opinion.

Comment: .net framework 2 is just 20 MB and 3.5 is 300 MB, My app is only 1MB or less in size, who install 300MB for my app?

Comment: This does not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

### '

### i changed a few things. & Thankyou

Public rtbTemp As New RichTextBox()

```
Public Sub ChangeFontSize(ByVal rtb As RichTextBox, ByVal fontSize As Single)

    'This method should handle cases that occur when multiple fonts/styles are selected
    ' Parameters:-
    ' fontSize - the fontsize to be applied, eg 33.5

    If fontSize <= 0.0 Then

        Throw New System.InvalidProgramException("Invalid font size parameter to ChangeFontSize")

    End If

    Dim rtb1start As Integer = rtb.SelectionStart

    Dim len As Integer = rtb.SelectionLength

    Dim rtbTempStart As Integer = 0

    ' If len <= 1 and there is a selection font, amend and return

    If len <= 1 AndAlso rtb.SelectionFont IsNot Nothing Then

        rtb.SelectionFont = New Font(rtb.SelectionFont.FontFamily, fontSize, rtb.SelectionFont.Style)

        Return

    End If

    ' Step through the selected text one char at a time

    rtbTemp.Rtf = rtb.SelectedRtf

    For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1

        rtbTemp.[Select](rtbTempStart + i, 1)

        rtbTemp.SelectionFont = New Font(rtbTemp.SelectionFont.FontFamily, fontSize, rtbTemp.SelectionFont.Style)

    Next

    ' Replace & reselect

    rtbTemp.[Select](rtbTempStart, len)

    rtb.SelectedRtf = rtbTemp.SelectedRtf

    rtb.[Select](rtb1start, len)

    Return

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Here I changed Few things

Public rtbTemp As New RichTextBox()

```
Public Sub ChangeFontSize(ByVal rtb As RichTextBox, ByVal fontSize As Single, ByVal fntName As String)

    If fontSize <= 0.0 Then
        Throw New System.InvalidProgramException("Invalid font size parameter to ChangeFontSize")
    End If
    Dim rtb1start As Double = rtb.SelectionStart
    Dim len As Double = rtb.SelectionLength
    Dim rtbTempStart As Double = 0
    ' If len <= 1 and there is a selection font, amend and return
    If len <= 1 AndAlso rtb.SelectionFont IsNot Nothing Then
        rtb.SelectionFont = New Font(fntName, fontSize, rtb.SelectionFont.Style)
        Return
    End If
    ' Step through the selected text one char at a time
    rtbTemp.Rtf = rtb.SelectedRtf
    For i As Double = 0 To len - 1
        rtbTemp.[Select](rtbTempStart + i, 1)
        rtbTemp.SelectionFont = New Font(fntName, fontSize, rtbTemp.SelectionFont.Style)
    Next

    ' Replace & reselect
    rtbTemp.[Select](rtbTempStart, len)
    rtb.SelectedRtf = rtbTemp.SelectedRtf
    rtb.[Select](rtb1start, len)
    Return

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

'// Here i Changed ie. This .... Thankyou.
'//**Code**

Public Sub ChangeFontSize(ByVal rtb As RichTextBox, ByVal fontSize As Single, ByVal fntName As String)
If fontSize <= 0.0 Then
Throw New System.InvalidProgramException("Invalid font size parameter to ChangeFontSize")
End If
Dim rtb1start As Double = rtb.SelectionStart
Dim len As Double = rtb.SelectionLength
Dim rtbTempStart As Double = 0
' If len <= 1 and there is a selection font, amend and return
If len <= 1 AndAlso rtb.SelectionFont IsNot Nothing Then
rtb.SelectionFont = New Font(fntName, fontSize, rtb.SelectionFont.Style)
Return
End If
' Step through the selected text one char at a time
rtbTemp.Rtf = rtb.SelectedRtf
For i As Double = 0 To len - 1
rtbTemp.[Select](rtbTempStart + i, 1)
rtbTemp.SelectionFont = New Font(fntName, fontSize, rtbTemp.SelectionFont.Style)
Next

```
    ' Replace & reselect
    rtbTemp.[Select](rtbTempStart, len)
    rtb.SelectedRtf = rtbTemp.SelectedRtf
    rtb.[Select](rtb1start, len)
    Return

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).